# Virtual machine network settings to connect two virtual machines

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Connecting two virtual machines (Windows Server + Windows client) using Virtual Box is not a challenge, you only need to set network settings to `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` on both. Then you can connect to server using Active Directory without issues.

But how to do it using HyperV? There are only two options - `No connection` and `Default Switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the ability to
[Create a virtual switch for Hyper-V virtual machines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines)
and use it instead of the default switch.

Virtual switches can have three types:

**External virtual switch**

This switch allows:

- VM to VM
- VM to host
- VM to outside network via host physical NIC

**Internal virtual switch**

This is the closest to the host-only network. It allows:

- VM to VM
- VM to host

**Private virtual switch**

This switch allows only:

- VM to VM.

Comment: With internal virtual switch ping always ends with general failure.

Comment: Do you have static IPs?

Comment: yep they are static. Works fine on VB, HyperV refuses to work.

Comment: one VM lost IP configuration after changing switch but now its just request timed out. Configuration is identical to Virtual Box so I guess just its issue with Hyper V. And to think software full of such issues costs real money.

Comment: Hyper-V works, and works well. These might be configuration leftovers from the time that the VMs were on VB. Check well their actual Hyper-V settings and guest network configuration.